# Dual display setup - only one displayed after logon

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, display

During boot process my desktop shows both Monitors, but after log I only get one.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10

When I go into Displays its still only shows on Monitor.

Here is my graphics card details:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G72 [GeForce 7300 LE] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Dell Device 0405
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at dd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at de000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at dfe00000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidia_96, nvidia_173, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

Answer (score 1):

With the proprietary Nvidia driver installed, you should use Nvidia Settings, to setup dual monitors. Look for it in the menu (or just search for 'nvidia'), it should have been installed along with the driver.

Comment: nvidia settings does not work, cant get the application to run in either ubuntu or gnome

Answer (score 0):

There are several bug listings regarding external monitors.
Examples:

- [Intel Core i3 External Monitor Wavy Output](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/614238)
- [[arrandale] desktop is messed up with external monitors (x86_64)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/745112)

It's very serious that display issues aren't getting precedence over other bugs.
I've been experiencing issues with the external monitor for more than half a year.
I love Ubuntu and Linux and hopefully the issues will be resolved in the near future.

Comment: most things work in 11.04, but the move to 11.10 has messed things up, i am going to downgrade and wait for 12.04

Comment: Fresh install of 11.10 solved the external monitor problems for me. It seems that it was just a bad upgrade process.

Comment: cool, thanks, but I have it all working now on 11.04